# Error code in saving images by PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-code, phasset, phphotolibrary

My code uses ALAssetsLibrary to get/save images on iPhone so far.
And Currently I'm changing over from **ALAssetsLibrary** to **PHPhotoLibrary**.

In the migration I looked for error codes such as,
***ALAssetsLibraryWriteBusyError*** and ***ALAssetsLibraryWriteDiskSpaceError***, but I couldn't.
When my application cannot save images. I want to let users know the reason by showing error dialog.

My code for saving images is like below,

```
- (void)savePhotoFile:(NSURL *)fileURL completion:(savePhotoFileCompletion)completion
{
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

            PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest;
            assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:fileURL];

            if (self.assetCollection) {
                PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest =
                    [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.assetCollection];
                [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[ [assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset] ]];
            }
        }

        completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *_Nullable error) {
            DBGLog(@"success=%@, error=%@", (success ? @"YES" : @"NO"), error);
            completion(success, error);
        }];
}
```

Does anyone know the corresponding error codes in PHPhotoLibrary ?
I'd really appreciate any information about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`+ creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:` is for video. I think you should use 
`+ creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL:`
 instead.

Comment: as a usual you can check NSError code, userInfo properties collect error information and prepare readable message for users.

Comment: @AliKıran Yes I know about the userInfo in NSError. I'd like to know the **corresponding** error info to ALAssetsLibraryWriteDiskSpaceError and ALAssetsLibraryWriteBusyError. If possible I implement retry code internally.